# Adding local variable to List

Tags: c#

```
public class C
{
    private List<myClass> _list = new List<myClass>();
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        myClass myClassInstance = new myClass();
        // working with myClassInstance 
        _list.Add(myClassInstance);
    }
}
```

Problem is that List doesn't get populated, _list.Count is always 0 :(

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid C#...

Comment: First of all, `class` is a system word and you shouldn't name variables using this word

Comment: You can't use keywords as variables.  try  `@class`, or `theClass`

Comment: looks like javascript

Comment: `function ()` should be `private void <name>()`

Comment: You may want to look to some basic C# Tutorials. There are multiple errors with your code. I think doing some basic tutorial would help. For example you can find some help here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I know that it isn't valid, but I've just tried to explain a problem, and not to copy many lines of code...

Comment: @user3055186: It's very hard to guess what your actual problem is, when the code that you post is so far from the actual code that you use. Try to put together a working example that demonstrates the same problem that you have. By doing that you may actually spot yourself what the problem is, and if not others can help you.

Comment: thanks for putting code that make some sense... Are you sure that `_list.Count` did not change after `_list.Add(myClassInstance);`?

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, it is depends on your desing of `myClass` but I see two things;

- `class` is a [`keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), that's why you should use it as a `@class`

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid
>   identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

- your `function` method missed a *return type* which is [`void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) looks okey for your case.

Comment: I didn't care for syntax mistakes, so my problem is that List isn't getting populated for some reasons...

Comment: @user3055186 _I didn't care for syntax mistakes_ Really? Then how do you think your program going to work?

Comment: No, I meant I didn't care about syntax in posting question, not in code ofcourse :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename both the instance of myClass and function to something OTHER than C# keywords.  At that point you can add the value to the list

```
public class C
{
    private List<myClass> _list = new List<myClass>();
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        myClass myClassInstance = new myClass();
        // working with myClassInstance 
        _list.Add(myClassInstance);
    }
}
```